# Strange casting to float when array is added as new DataFrame row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have observe strange type casting when I initialize my DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['day', 'switch_ip', 'mac', 'type'])
df.mac = test_data.mac.astype('uint64')
df.info()

for mac in range(5):
    df.loc[len(df)] = ['file_name', 'switch_ip', mac, 0]

df.info()
```

My mac columns changes own type to float. Why? It is critical for me and I cannot understand what are wrong...

Comment: If you have a `NA` value in that column, it cannot be saved as `int` and converted to `float`

Comment: But I haven't here any NA...?